# Different Options for traceSpecification

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

i am trying to figure out all the log levels in worklight / Liberty level, I am not able to find all the options for traceSpecification, I do understand that we have traceSpecification="*=audit=enabled:com.worklight.*=info=enabled" with consoleLogLevel="INFO", But i am not able to undersatnd what is the significance and combination of both attributes with options.

Appreciate all your answers

Thanks
Djrecker

Answer (score 1):

The **traceSpecification** specifies what output you receive in the **trace.log** file. For example `traceSpecification="*=info:com.ibm.worklight.*=fine:com.worklight.*=fine:com.ibm.puremeap.*=fine"` will show traces from Worklight. (com.ibm.puremeap is the package name for IBM Application Center.)

The **consoleLogLevel** specifies what output you receive in the **console.log** file.

The detailed documentation of these features is at [Liberty profile: Logging and Trace](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html?cp=SSEQTP_8.5.5%2F1-16-0-0).

Comment: Can you please tell me where can i find the different options like the one have suggested above, info:com.ibm.worklight.*=fine:com.worklight.*=fine:com.ibm.puremeap.*=fine

Comment: Look at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/admin/r_logging_and_monitoring_mechanisms.html. The different options depend on the application server you used. Links are provided in the above URL